# Angularjs variable inside classic function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a problem where I can't find solution.  I am searching the internet but it seems that there is not much information.

I have a controller that I need to fill a variable and access it within a classical function of javascript. Any idea how I do it?

This is the controller:

```
moduloMapa.controller('controlIndexMap', function($scope, serverService) {
        var clase = "liga";
        $scope.ligasMap = serverService.getPageLigas(clase).then(function(datos1) {
            $scope.ligasMap = datos1['list'];
        });
    });
```

And this the function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function testVariable(){
//I NEED $scope.ligasMap in this context.
}
</script>
```

Ty for help :)

Comment: can't you make testVariable receive ligasMap variable, and call testVariable from controller?

Comment: I have no access to scope.ligasMap within the function, is undefined.

Comment: Where is this classic function invoked from, a button click? What are you trying to do here (high level)?

Answer (score 0):

You can define global variables in your script that you can access from your script tag/controller.

### Example

Controller

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.test = "Test String";
    testVar = $scope.test
    
    $scope.run = function(){
        testF();
    }
}
```

Template

```
<div ng-app>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      
      testF = function(){
          console.log(testVar);
      }
      
  </script>
    
  <span onclick="testF()">Click me( I am outside the controller accessing data from inside the controller )</span>
  <br /><br /><br />  
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      
      <span ng-click="run()">Click me ( I am inside the controller executing a function outside it )</span>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6xYrd/1/

I would however not design my application like this, it's wrong by defenition. But if you must, then this is one way of doing it.

Comment: you put the example works but I need to click on any site, it should automatically load the functions assigned to, you know?

Comment: Iam not sure that I understand your question. The above example automatically loads the function. It does not need to be invoked from the controller to work, you can create javascript that can access the controller-data that is moved to global variables.

Comment: Can I have another example of what you're saying

Comment: The point is. When you define global variables, either inside or outside a controller, you can access those variables from anywhere on your page.

Comment: ok, I understand what you say. :) But the fiddle not is updated. Ty!